# Нужно расставить единицы в матрице, чтобы они не с соприкасались друг с другом

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Вот условие:**
Имеется двумерное игровое поле размером N x N (N - натуральное число, вводится с клавиатуры), представленное в виде вложенного списка:

**P = [[0] * N for i in range(N)]**

Требуется расставить в нем случайным образом M = 10 единиц (целочисленных) так, чтобы они не соприкасались друг с другом (то есть, вокруг каждой единицы должны быть нули, либо граница поля).

**Вот код:**

```
import random


random.seed(1)

N = int(input())
P = [[0] * N for i in range(N)]
M = 10

while M > 0:
    row = random.randint(0, N - 1)
    pos = random.randint(0, N - 1)
    if P[row-1][pos] + P[row - len(P) + 1][pos] + P[row][pos] + P[row][pos - len(P) + 1] + P[row][pos - 1] + P[row - len(P) + 1][pos - len(P) + 1] + P[row - len(P) + 1][pos - 1] + P[row - 1][pos - len(P) + 1] + P[row - 1][pos-1] == 0:
        P[row][pos] = 1
        M -= 1
    else:
        continue
```

В матрице 10х10 у меня все ок. Проблема в том что в матрице 7х7 тоже должно поместиться 10 единиц, но у меня влезает только 9 единиц, и дальше начинается бесконечный цикл, который ищет место для 10 единицы. У меня есть мысль что условие строгое, но я не уверен.

Comment: и какой вопрос-то? еслип предыдущие 9 единиц стоят так, что больше нет подходящего места для десятой, то хоть обыщись, места не найдешь.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, но по условию в матрице 7х7 может поместиться 10 единиц

Comment: в 7х7 даже 16 поместиться может. Но вероятность получить такое расположение случайной расстановкой исчезающе мала.

Comment: Насколько "случайной" должна быть расстановка? Выберите из диапазона от "вероятности любых возможных расстановок должны быть равны" через "вероятности могут быть различны, но не могут быть нулевые" до "какие попало вероятности".

Comment: Думаю, что для начала лучше исправить три проблемы, что я выделил в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. При случайной расстановке вариант с 10 единицами не гарантирован.
   Например, имея квадрат с вертикальной нумерацией от A до F и горизонтальной от 1 до  7, мы можем получить ситуацию, при которой сначала будут заняты ячейки B2, B5, E2, E5, что полностью выведет из доступности квадрат 6x6 (A1-F6). Дальнейшая случайная расстановка может позволить ещё пять - B7, E7, G2, G5, G7. Итого гарантировано только 9.
   **В таком случае нужна проверка на зацикливание и потом перезапуск. Или вообще по-другому делать - см.комментарий Романа ниже.**
2. **Ваши псевдослучайные генераторы при всех прогонах выдают одинаковые последовательности. Надо убрать `random.seed (1)`.**
3. Вы для каждого найденного элемента рассчитываете все девять "запретных" полей, хотя у граничных элементов их будет меньше. Да еще и неправильно рассчитываете. Даже если компонент (например) P[0][3] и будет разрешенным, то `P[row-1][pos]` начнет проверять граничность с компонентом P[-1][3], что эквивалентно P[6][3], а этот элемент не имеет никакого отношения к P[0][3]. Вы какой-то тор реализовали, а не квадрат.
   **Надо правильную проверку сделать, убрав элементы с минусом**
   (добавить что-то вроде `row_c = row - 1 if row > 0 else 0`,  а все индексы `row - 1` заменив на `row_c` и аналогично с `pos`)
4. **`else` лучше убрать.** Смысла он не несет, цикл и без `continue` продолжится.

Comment: Такая итерприрация "случайной расстановки" неконструктивна и для даной задачи, уверен, неправильна. Очевидно, что 10 единиц можно расставить в квадрате 7х7. Очевидно, что не одним способом. В задаче под "случайная расстановка" имеется ввиду "случайная из доступных/разрешенных", а не "со случайным размещением единиц по одной".

Comment: Я написал этот ответ, отталкиваясь от конкретного кода, так как вопрос по нему, как я понимаю, а не "выполните мне домашку".